# jquery inline image edit plugin

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload

Im searching for a jquery Plugin that will help to change the image profile when hovering my mouse on the image profile, and upload the changed image using ajax after confirmation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these links as a startup.
http://jqueryplugin.net/best-jquery-file-upload-plugins-with-image-previews/
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-file-upload/

These links have a  number of plugins that can be used for image plugin.

You can search in Stack overflow for other issues you may have.

Thanks!!